# RIDK install: error: database 'mingw32' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))

Tags: ruby, msys2, ruby-install, rubyinstaller

I get this error when trying to install MSYS2/MINGW:

```
>ridk install
   1 - MSYS2 base installation
   2 - MSYS2 system update
   3 - MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain

Which components shall be installed? If unsure press ENTER [1,2,3] 3

MSYS2 seems to be already installed
Install MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain ...
> pacman -S --needed --noconfirm autoconf autoconf2.13 autogen automake-wrapper automake1.10 automake1.11 automake1.12 automake1.13 automake1.14 automake1.15 automake1.6 automake1.7 automake1.8 automake1.9 diffutils file gawk grep libtool m4 make patch pkg-config sed texinfo texinfo-tex wget mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git mingw-w64-x86_64-libmangle-git mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git mingw-w64-x86_64-make mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config mingw-w64-x86_64-tools-git mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git
error: mingw32: signature from "David Macek <david.macek.0@gmail.com>" is marginal trust
error: mingw64: signature from "David Macek <david.macek.0@gmail.com>" is marginal trust
error: msys: signature from "David Macek <david.macek.0@gmail.com>" is marginal trust
error: database 'mingw32' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'mingw64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'msys' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
Install MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain failed
Installation failed: pacman failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `ridk install` just installs MSYS2 https://www.msys2.org/. They switched up their package maintainers so the keys were bad: https://www.msys2.org/news/#2020-06-29-new-packagers. Pacman is their package manager (like `apt-get`, `yum`, `gem`). I either had an old version or my old Ruby 2.4 was installing an old version (version: '20161025'). I happened to have Chocolatey and there was a `msys2` package so I used

```
choco upgrade msys2  # this installed it. i did not have it installed via chocolatey
ridk version  # still showed an old version and would not work
pacman -U xz  # xz is like gzip - this gave the errors above
choco uninstall msys2  # this didn't do much
del \msys2  # have to manually delete the directory
choco upgrade msys2  # this installed a recent version
ridk install  # have to install the make and c++ tools, so include choice 3
```

It installed 49 packages and now `make` works.

Answer (score 0):

This error put my head in a spin. I ended up uninstalling ruby installer and downloading the latest version with the devkit. Updated and good to go. Hope this helps. Cheers.